# VB.NET - Проблемы с replace через function

Tags: функции, vb.net, replace

Идет у меня значит функция:

```
Public Shared Function strEnc(ByVal dga As String) As String
        dga = dga.Replace(" ", " 00000 ")
        dga = dga.Replace("a", " 00100 ")
        ...
        dga = dga.Replace("`9`", " 05029 ")
        Return dga
End Function
```

И при использовании функции возвращается тот же текст что и был введен, то есть никаких изменений, что ввел, то и выдал, хотя должен вернуть замененную строку. Я уже минут 30 сижу и не понимаю в чем проблема. Вне функции код работает, а в ней уже нет.

Comment: все правильно отрабатывает, покажите как используете функцию

Comment: @slippyk
Было так: (Не работало)
`output.Text = strEnc(input.Text)`
Теперь так: (Не работает)
`Dim dd = input.Text
strEnc(dd)
output.Text = dd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если правильно понимаю, `input` и `output` - поля для ввода текста `TextBox`.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    output.Text = StrEnc(input.Text)
End Sub

Public Function StrEnc(dga As String) As String
    dga = dga.Replace(" ", " 00000 ")
    dga = dga.Replace("a", " 00100 ")
    dga = dga.Replace("9", " 05029 ")
    Return dga
End Function
```

Можно передавать по ссылке параметр, тогда получится:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dga As String = input.Text
    StrEnc(dga)
    output.Text = dga
End Sub

Public Function StrEnc(ByRef dga As String) As String
    dga = dga.Replace(" ", " 00000 ")
    dga = dga.Replace("a", " 00100 ")
    dga = dga.Replace("9", " 05029 ")
    Return dga
End Function
```

Все отрабатывает как надо:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]